# android studio use to much ram on ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu

can anyone tell me why android studio on Ubuntu use to much ram memory and why it is so painful to code.
My specs are:
cpu: i3-2310m
ram: 4gb ddr3
system: ubuntu 16.04.1

I had android studio on win 10 and with emulator was used only 3,4gb of ram.
Codding was not so great on win 10, but definitely less painful (less lagging)than on ubuntu. 
I use the same android studio (2.1) and the same project but,
on Ubuntu use whole ram and use 1,1 gb of swap and emulator now is lagging. how is that possible, should not android studio be less demanding on ubuntu than on windows os?

Comment: You will see great performance with a SSD and increased RAM

Comment: "I had android studio on win 10 and with emulator was used only 3,4gb of ram" -- most likely, you are not comparing memory usage exactly the same in both OSes. Measuring memory usage in modern operating systems is a complex process. "should not android studio be less demanding on ubuntu than on windows os?" -- not necessarily. There is nothing intrinsic to Ubuntu that makes programs consume less resources on Ubuntu than the same programs on Windows. Behavior will vary by program.

Comment: I have kingston xfury 120gb ssd and i will try with upgrading ram on 8 gb. Thanks

Comment: Its IntelliJ IDEA (inside Android Studio) - eating much ram usually. Even 8Gb may be not enough on large projects.

Answer (score 2):

> and why it is so painful to code. My specs are: cpu: i3-2310m ram: 4gb ddr3 system:

"4gb" - that's why. i3 is also not helping really as the whole IDE, gradle and stuff needs some horse power. What's your storage? 5400 hdd or maybe something better?

Comment: I have ssd 120gb, and i know that i need better laptop. Because of that i try with Ubuntu i read on web that is less demanding, but obviously in my case not. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Ubuntu may be less demanding, but you still got Java, IntellijJ and gradle in the play. And I got far better specs and still miss old Eclipse times where all things worked faster

Answer (score 0):

As immediate solution try to decrease memory in AVD (emulator) settings, try 512Mb.

Also you can try power saving mode (it can consume less memory too) pressing on the bottom-right button, see the screenshot:
[image: Highlighting Level]

You can even try to disable Inspections in this menu, if you're comfortable without them.

But the real solution is only to buy more RAM, unfortunately...